# Somehow it's not copying

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub GetTW_Data()

ThisWorkbook.Activate 'start in THIS workbook
Sheets(1).Select 'switch to data import sheet

'Opens source file (this filename never changes)
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Test 1\1 eBay BrandProgress.xls", ReadOnly:=True

Workbooks("1 eBay BrandProgress.xls").Activate 'switch to source workbook
Sheets(1).Select.UsedRange.Copy 'switch to source data sheet

ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Return to THIS workbook

[B5].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste data to import start cell
[a1].Select 'cancels highlighted paste region

Workbooks("1 eBay BrandProgress.xls").Close 'source data workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what your'e asking. Please clarify with additional details, specifically what is meant by "it's not copying"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to avoid using Select and Activate.

Set the workbooks, worksheets and ranges to variables and use them.

Also when pasting just values avoid the clipboard for speed.

```
Sub GetTW_Data()
Dim tWb As Workbook
Dim ebayWb As Workbook
Dim tWs As Worksheet
Dim ebayWs As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set tWb = ThisWorkbook
Set tWs = tWb.Sheets(1)

Set ebayWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test 1\1 eBay BrandProgress.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
Set ebayWs = ebayWb.Sheets(1)

Set rng = ebayWs.UsedRange

tWs.Range("B5").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

ebayWb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: It's pasting by values. How can I do it for Pasting as it is with the formatting from the source file?

Comment: Your code only pastes the values not the format.  So I simply assigned the values directly.  If you want the format then you need to `rng.Copy tWs.Range("B5")` instead of the other line.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're attempting to paste the contents of the entire

```
UserRange
```

sheet to

```
Sheet(1)
```

, but that you're pasting into cell B5. You are pasting more rows and columns into the destination than are available, as you are missing the first row and the first four columns in the destination.

Either change the copy range to account for that discrepancy, or paste into cell A1 on the destination